# SQL Server Link Table Connection Corrupts

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, ms-access, linked-server

I have linked my **Microsoft Access Database** tables into my **SQL Server** database using **Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0** as the provider.

I also have a C# application where I query the data from these linked Access tables. In other words, I am querying my Access DB tables but my connection string is pointing my SQL Server Database.

My problem is, when I send around 4-5 rapid requests to my SQL Server to bring back data from linked tables, my connection gets corrupted. To fix this issue I have to restart the SQL Server service.

I can understand the connection is alright if I right click on my Linked Server and choose **Test Connection**. This should return the message: `The test connection to the linked server succeeded`. Otherwise it will cause Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to freeze.

[image]

Does anyone know what might be causing this problem ?

Comment: What is the purpose of keeping your tables in Access?

Comment: @WEI_DBA I have an ERP application running on Access thats the reason I am using Access.

Comment: Then why not just point directly at Access instead of going through SQL?

Comment: @WEI_DBA Its a very long story but to give a short answer I am trying to use Entity framework for ms access. Since EF does not support Access I had to work around things...